# ImproperlyConfigured: Error loading MySQLdb module: No module named MySQLdb

Tags: python, mysql, django, google-app-engine, module

I'm working on a Google App Engine project and have been running into issues trying to set up the basic Django Admin Site with MySQL. I have searched around about this question, but all I see people posting about deals with running apps locally. In my situation, I'm getting an error when running the app in Google App Engine.

To be more specific about the issue, I get the following error in the logs for my application:

```
ImproperlyConfigured: Error loading MySQLdb module: No module named MySQLdb
```

This makes it seem like MySQL isn't even installed, which doesn't really make sense. It should be accessible by default in GAE. Is there another issue that I'm not seeing? This is confusing for me because it doesn't even give me a specific line to look at, or any kind of lead.

I've looked through the GAE documentation for Django and CloudSQL but nothing I had seemed out of place. I also took a look at the example Django app and all of my content didn't seem to conflict with what they had there.

The full log is here:

```
    E 21:59:53.098 Internal Server Error: /admin/
  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/third_party/django-1.4/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 87, in get_response
      response = middleware_method(request)
    File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/third_party/django-1.4/django/contrib/sessions/middleware.py", line 10, in process_request
      engine = import_module(settings.SESSION_ENGINE)
    File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/third_party/django-1.4/django/utils/importlib.py", line 35, in import_module
      __import__(name)
    File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/third_party/django-1.4/django/contrib/sessions/backends/db.py", line 3, in <module>
      from django.db import IntegrityError, transaction, router
    File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/third_party/django-1.4/django/db/__init__.py", line 40, in <module>
      backend = load_backend(connection.settings_dict['ENGINE'])
    File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/third_party/django-1.4/django/db/__init__.py", line 34, in __getattr__
      return getattr(connections[DEFAULT_DB_ALIAS], item)
    File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/third_party/django-1.4/django/db/utils.py", line 92, in __getitem__
      backend = load_backend(db['ENGINE'])
    File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/third_party/django-1.4/django/db/utils.py", line 24, in load_backend
      return import_module('.base', backend_name)
    File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/third_party/django-1.4/django/utils/importlib.py", line 35, in import_module
      __import__(name)
    File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/third_party/django-1.4/django/db/backends/mysql/base.py", line 16, in <module>
      raise ImproperlyConfigured("Error loading MySQLdb module: %s" % e)
  ImproperlyConfigured: Error loading MySQLdb module: No module named MySQLdb
E 21:59:53.227 Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/runtime/wsgi.py", line 267, in Handle
      result = handler(dict(self._environ), self._StartResponse)
    File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/third_party/django-1.4/django/core/handlers/wsgi.py", line 241, in __call__
      response = self.get_response(request)
    File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/third_party/django-1.4/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 177, in get_response
      response = self.handle_uncaught_exception(request, resolver, sys.exc_info())
    File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/third_party/django-1.4/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 219, in handle_uncaught_exception
      return debug.technical_500_response(request, *exc_info)
    File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/third_party/django-1.4/django/views/debug.py", line 66, in technical_500_response
      html = reporter.get_traceback_html()
    File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/third_party/django-1.4/django/views/debug.py", line 287, in get_traceback_html
      return t.render(c)
    File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/third_party/django-1.4/django/template/base.py", line 140, in render
      return self._render(context)
    File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/third_party/django-1.4/django/template/base.py", line 134, in _render
      return self.nodelist.render(context)
    File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/third_party/django-1.4/django/template/base.py", line 823, in render
      bit = self.render_node(node, context)
    File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/third_party/django-1.4/django/template/debug.py", line 74, in render_node
      return node.render(context)
    File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/third_party/django-1.4/django/template/debug.py", line 84, in render
      output = self.filter_expression.resolve(context)
    File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/third_party/django-1.4/django/template/base.py", line 599, in resolve
      new_obj = func(obj, *arg_vals)
    File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/third_party/django-1.4/django/template/defaultfilters.py", line 718, in date
      return format(value, arg)
    File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/third_party/django-1.4/django/utils/dateformat.py", line 310, in format
      return df.format(format_string)
    File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/third_party/django-1.4/django/utils/dateformat.py", line 33, in format
      pieces.append(force_unicode(getattr(self, piece)()))
    File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/third_party/django-1.4/django/utils/dateformat.py", line 214, in r
      return self.format('D, j M Y H:i:s O')
    File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/third_party/django-1.4/django/utils/dateformat.py", line 33, in format
      pieces.append(force_unicode(getattr(self, piece)()))
    File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/third_party/django-1.4/django/utils/encoding.py", line 71, in force_unicode
      s = unicode(s)
    File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/third_party/django-1.4/django/utils/functional.py", line 121, in __unicode_cast
      return func(*self.__args, **self.__kw)
    File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/third_party/django-1.4/django/utils/translation/__init__.py", line 86, in ugettext
      return _trans.ugettext(message)
    File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/third_party/django-1.4/django/utils/translation/trans_real.py", line 278, in ugettext
      return do_translate(message, 'ugettext')
    File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/third_party/django-1.4/django/utils/translation/trans_real.py", line 268, in do_translate
      _default = translation(settings.LANGUAGE_CODE)
    File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/third_party/django-1.4/django/utils/translation/trans_real.py", line 183, in translation
      default_translation = _fetch(settings.LANGUAGE_CODE)
    File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/third_party/django-1.4/django/utils/translation/trans_real.py", line 160, in _fetch
      app = import_module(appname)
    File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/third_party/django-1.4/django/utils/importlib.py", line 35, in import_module
      __import__(name)
    File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/third_party/django-1.4/django/contrib/admin/__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
      from django.contrib.admin.helpers import ACTION_CHECKBOX_NAME
    File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/third_party/django-1.4/django/contrib/admin/helpers.py", line 2, in <module>
      from django.contrib.admin.util import (flatten_fieldsets, lookup_field,
    File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/third_party/django-1.4/django/contrib/admin/util.py", line 1, in <module>
      from django.db import models
    File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/third_party/django-1.4/django/db/__init__.py", line 40, in <module>
      backend = load_backend(connection.settings_dict['ENGINE'])
    File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/third_party/django-1.4/django/db/__init__.py", line 34, in __getattr__
      return getattr(connections[DEFAULT_DB_ALIAS], item)
    File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/third_party/django-1.4/django/db/utils.py", line 92, in __getitem__
      backend = load_backend(db['ENGINE'])
    File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/third_party/django-1.4/django/db/utils.py", line 24, in load_backend
      return import_module('.base', backend_name)
    File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/third_party/django-1.4/django/utils/importlib.py", line 35, in import_module
      __import__(name)
    File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/third_party/django-1.4/django/db/backends/mysql/base.py", line 16, in <module>
      raise ImproperlyConfigured("Error loading MySQLdb module: %s" % e)
  ImproperlyConfigured: Error loading MySQLdb module: No module named MySQLdb
```

Relevant portions of settings.py:

```
import os

DEBUG = True
TEMPLATE_DEBUG = DEBUG

BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
    'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
    'NAME': 'userinformation',
    'USER': 'root',
    'HOST': '/cloudsql/eloquent-ratio-109701:api-instance',
    }
}

TEMPLATE_LOADERS = (
    'django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader',
    'django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader',
    'django.template.loaders.eggs.Loader',
)

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
)

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'Chimera.urls'

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'Chimera.wsgi.app'

INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.admindocs',
    'API',
)
```

If you have any idea what could be going on, I'd really appreciate pointing me in the right direction. I can post any more significant source files here as well.

Answer (score 0):

Did you specify the `MySQLdb` library in your `app.yaml` config?

GAE has some specific support for using Django, I'd strongly suggest going through the [Django Support](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/cloud-sql/django) documentation and the [Django App example](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/appengine-django-skeleton).

**Update** - an experiment:

I just added this to the `libraries` section of my (non-Django) app's `.yaml` file:

```
- name: MySQLdb
  version: "latest"
```

And added this to one of my handlers:

```
        import MySQLdb
        print MySQLdb.apilevel
```

After deploying the changes on GAE and triggering the handler I got this log entry (same `2.0` content as on my dev server):

[image]

Which IMHO proves `MySQLdb` is available in GAE and can be imported with no issues.

Comment: I did specify it:

    - name: MySQLdb
      version: "latest"

Also I have checked out both of the links you have posted there (I mentioned it in my question) but unfortunately couldn't come up with anything significant to help me resolve the problem.

Comment: Oops, I just later noticed you were the receiver of the same doc pointers earlier on another question, sorry about that :) Updating the answer now qith an experiment I did.

Comment: No problem, thanks for the pointers and thanks for giving some ideas to help out!

Comment: @MichaelFourre, Have you tested the recommendation in Dan's answer to determine conclusively if the `MySQLdb` module gets loaded?  If so, what were your results?